# How can I override the default Apache HTML directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Probably a simple one, but this has me confused.

I'm running an EC2 instance which installs Apache 2.2 to the box once provisioned. I don't have access to `a2enmod` there but I need to change `AllowOverride None` to be `AllowOverride FileInfo` for the default `/var/www/html` directory where my app gets installed to.

This is configured in `httpd.conf` but I don't want to have to SSH into every new instance of my app and manually change that setting. I have a build script which copies the below file to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/my-app.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This doesn't work though, I presume because the part in `httpd.conf` that loads files from `conf.d/*.conf` comes *before* the part where `/var/www/html` is defined (and `AllowOverride` is therefore set back to `None`).

How can I configure this so that setting is what I want (eg. `FileInfo`) without manually editing that file? I need this to be scriptable.

Comment: when you say it doesnt work, what is happening? what is the log output?  would it be acceptable to you to edit `httpd.conf` via a script?

Comment: Sorry – just a standard 404 error in the browser when I hit a page that a `.htaccess` file should be rewriting (a Wordpress install where I'm removing `index.php` from the path). In the Apache logs I just get `File does not exist: /var/www/html/category`). I'd accept editing it via a script I guess but that feels a bit kludgy.

Comment: im assuming `/etc/httpd/conf.d/my-app.conf` where you putting your `<Directory>` container is a VHOST config? it it being loaded? - does the rewriting work if you temporarily change `AllowOverride FileInfo` to `AllowOverride All` ?

Comment: Ahh it looks like you're right – the contents of `my-app.conf` was literally the `<Directory>` part I posted in my question. When I wrapped this in a `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag it worked – my syntax was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your `<Directory>` container and the directives within it to take effect, it should be in a `<VirtualHost>` container that Apache matches when a request is made to your app.
Try re-checking your configuration and making sure that your config files are setup properly with the correct syntax